# I need guidance on how installing python packages in Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Can someone help me with installing packages in atom for python. I am trying to import requests, but it says module doesn't exist. I have it installed though. It works fine on IDLE editor.

Comment: You don't install Python packages "in Atom". You'd change which Python executable Atom runs that has the packages you want

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: I've not used Atom recently, but it should be in the Python plugin settings somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! Python 2 was the default, thats what was causing the error. You have to change it to make python 3 the default.

This is how you can do that

unlink /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3/usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages from the command line. Go to Terminal or iTerm2 and type `pip install package_name`. If you are using virtual environments activate an environment and then type the pip command. If you are using python-3 then type `pip3 install package-name`. If you are running Anaconda ignore above and instead type `conda install package-name` after you've activated virtual environment.

Comment: Thats the problem. I have done all that. But it still won't let me use it. It works in IDLE, but i really want to use atom. I even tried it in sublime text but it didn't let me use it there either.